# Cannot overwrite Symbolic Link RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, symlink, redhat

I have created a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /some/dir new_dir
```

Now I want to overwrite the symbolic link to point to a new location and it will not overwrite. I have tried:

```
sudo ln -f -s /other/dir new_dir
```

I can always `sudo rm new_dir`, but I would rather have it overwrite accordingly if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
ln -sfn /other/dir new_dir
```

works for me. The `-n` doesn't dereference the destination symlink.

Comment: Good point. From the man page: `-h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it.  This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink which may point to a directory.`

Comment: `-n` is equivalent to `-h` (at least on MacOS X)

Answer (score 10):

You can create it and then move it:

```
sudo ln -f -s /other/dir __new_dir
sudo mv -Tf __new_dir new_dir
```

edit: Missing -Tf, to treat the directory as a regular file and don't prompt for overwrite.

This way you will overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Link from mikeytown2s comment is broken, i will explain why [redent84s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5250369/3900251) is better:

While

```
ln -sfn newDir currentDir
```

does the job, **it is not an atomic operation**, as you can see with strace:

```
$ strace ln -snf newDir currentDir 2>&1 | grep link
unlink("currentDir")         = 0
symlink("newDir", "currentDir") = 0
```

This is important when you have a webserver root pointing to that symlink. It could cause errors while the symlink is deleted and created again - even in the timespan of a microsecond.

To prevent errors use instead:

```
$ ln -s newDir tmpCurrentDir && mv -Tf tmpCurrentDir currentDir
```

This will create a temporary Link and after that **overwrite *currentDir* in an atomic operation**.